# Merging two string lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two series x and y. I want to merge them to create a new series: tag, but I'm not able to achieve the expected output. I've tried:

```
df['tag'] = df['x'] + df['y']
```

I've looked everywhere and haven't been able to find a solution to the problem.

**Current output:**

```
x                               y           tag
['fast food', 'american']   ['chicken'] ['fast food', 'american']['chicken']
```

**Expected output:**

```
x                               y           tag
['fast food', 'american']   ['chicken'] ['fast food', 'american', 'chicken']
```

**df.to_dict()**

```
{'x': "['fast food', 'american']",
 'y': "['chicken']"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that is `list` , so you may convert it into `list` , them you can `sum`

```
import ast
df.x = df.x.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df.y = df.y.apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['tag'] = df['x'] + df['y']
```

---

More info

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['y']=["['chicken']"]
df['x']=["['fast food', 'american']"]
df.applymap(type)
Out[295]: 
               y              x
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>


df.x = df.x.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df.y = df.y.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df.applymap(type)
Out[297]: 
                y               x
0  <class 'list'>  <class 'list'>
```

Comment: With this solution I must have a string list inside a list, how can I do that?

Comment: @Pepe in the mean time . convert it by `df=df.astype(str)`, then using above method

Comment: @Pepe did you try my method , ? `df.x = df.x.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df.y = df.y.apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['tag'] = df['x'] + df['y']`, this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `re.findall`:

```
import re

df.applymap(lambda x:re.findall("'(.+?)'", x)).sum(1)
```

which will return a `list` of `str`s:

```
                           x            y                             tag
0  ['fast food', 'american']  ['chicken']  [fast food, american, chicken]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the list and use apply to create your new column.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED**

Try this :

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['X']=[["chicken"]]
df['Y']=[["fast food","American"]]
df['tag']=df['X']+df['Y']
```

Comment: returns the same result I posted.

Comment: Apologies @Pepe . Updated the answer. Check it out